# how can i generate a item code value with auto increment integer plus an identification integer

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, integer, auto-increment

i'm creating a Itemcode for my inventory system i want the number system of integer values like this using java

for example this

for group 1 the code would be 001 -

```
0010001,
0010002
```

for group 2 the code would be 002-

```
0020003,
0020004
```

for group 3 the code would be 003-

```
0030005,
0030006
```

the items are encoded individually so when i add a new entry it will detect which group it belongs to and generate it desired item code the first 3 digits will be the corresponding Value identification in which group it belongs to the the next 4 digit code will just be the increment value..and would be stored as one integer using MySQL database

Comment: Helping with what? Please take the Tour and read the Help Center.

Comment: Your question is unclear.  1) You don't generate a format.  You generate values.  2) It is unclear if those are integers or strings. 3) It is unclear what the context for "generating" the numbers is. 4) You have shown two different "numbering" systems which would need to be generated in different ways.

Comment: thank you sorry i suck on english...i'll edit

Comment: @Pyne - yea ... well the ability to communicate effectively in writing with other IT people is vital ... if you are going to become an IT professional.

Answer (score 1):

You need to decide:

- Are the item codes to be represented as: one integer, a pair of integers (group & item), a string ... or something else.
- Is the numbering scheme per the first example or the second one.  (You seem to have chosen one scheme now ...)
- How you are going to populate the items and codes.  Do you read the codes?  Do you generate them all in one go while loading items from a file.  Do you create items and item ids one at a time (e.g. interactively).
- How is this information going to be "stored"?  In memory only?  In a flat file?  In a database?  (MySQL ... ?)

These decisions will largely dictate how you implement the item id "generation".

---

Basically, your problem here is that >>you<< need to figure out what the requirements are.  Once you have done that, the set of possible solutions will reduce to a manageable size, and you can then either work it out for yourself or ask a sensible question.